# I want the following regex to return 16 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code and want to be able to only return 10 characters after the 'LAST='. If there isn't 10 chars then don't return anything.

```
const value = 'LAST=uirndheusnrm38f6xxxxxxx'
const m = value.match(/LAST=([^\?&]+)/i)

if (m)
{
  console.log('i know it matched LAST= and returned the next 10 chars')
}
```

Is it possible without doing a `substr(0,10)` ?

Comment: Try `value.match(/LAST=([^?&]{10})$/i)` or `value.match(/LAST=([^?&]{10,})$/i)`. It is not clear: do you want 10 or more? You say you need to return 16 chars in the title, you say 10 in the question body.

Comment: Sorry only 10 characters.. I'll try that, thank you. Can't get my head around regex.

Comment: But 10 chars up to the end of string? Or get 10 chars and then ignore the rest, even if there are 11, 12  chars?

Comment: 10 only and if there's more or less than 10 return nothing.

Comment: Can you please use clear English? What does "10 only and if there's more or less than 10 return nothing" mean?

Answer (score 1):

In order to match exactly 10 characters we can use `{10}`:

```js
const m = value.match(/LAST=([^\?&]{10})/i);
```